# How can we filter charts with map hover using dc.js and leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, dc.js, dc.leaflet.js

I found the flash filter from [this](http://gamapserver.who.int/gho/interactive_charts/violence_prevention/homicides/atlas.html)

address.If you check this you will see when mouse hover map or other charts every elemnts filtering.I want to do like this with dc.js and leaflet maps.

How can we do this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQcH4XuoEns   Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the start of an answer, completely untested. I guarantee it will need some debugging and modification, but I hope it gives you a start.

```
chart.renderlet(function(chart) {
  chart.selectAll('rect').on("mouseover", function(d) {
    chart.filter(d.datum.key);
  });
});
```

Depending on the kind of chart, you will need to change `'rect'` to whatever are the elements of the chart you want you want to hover over. You can discover this by inspecting the DOM in the developer tools of your favorite browser. For example, for geoChoropleth it will be `'g.layer0'` or `'g.layer1'`, etc.

Hope this helps!